# Resposinve webdesign and positioning of elements

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a small widgetbox on my webpage. This widgets box contains these elements:

```
<table class="absence-widget-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="absence-widget-left">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" title="Next" aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-1"></i>
        </td>
        <td class="absence-widget-center" id="absence-date-container">
            @Html.Partial(MVC.ActivityWidget.Views.Partials.MyActivityAbsenceDateChanger, Model)
        </td>
        <td class="absence-widget-right">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" title="Previous"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And these elements have these styles in my css file:

```
.center-absence-widget-left {
    position: relative;
    left: 604px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.center-absence-widget-right {
    position: relative;
    left: 640px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.center-absence-widget-center {
    position: relative;
    left: 620px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 15%;
}
```

what i want to know is how do i add responsive design for these elements so when the page is not opened in a screen with less resolution, then the html elements responds to that and adjusts to it?

can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Take a look at CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put this line in your HTML `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

those are the media queries you should use. if you style a class outside the media queries it will be the default for that `class` or `id`.

For example you style your `class` and use media queries only for mobile `@media (max-width: 479px)...` if you change to a different screen size like tablet it will use the one you define outside your media queries

**mobile:**

```
@media (max-width: 479px){
 "your .class or #id here" {}
}
```

**tablet:**

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1024px){
 "your .class or #id here" {}
}
```

**desktop:**

```
 "your .class or #id here" {}
```

Comment: So this should be my css code ?

`@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .center-absence-widget-left {
        position: relative;
        left: 75px;
        padding-top: 13px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}`

Comment: yes, keep in mind if you replace it with your original css code, there wil be no styling for the other screen sizes and will be displaying plain html.

Comment: thank u for the help

Comment: I edited it a little so it would be more simple and better.